# Morphing NetworkX DiGraph using Relational Algebra

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, relational-algebra

I have a NetworkX DiGraph which contains nodes of two types, Agent, and Resource.

Notionally an adjacency matrix based on the edges (Agent->Resource) would look something like this:

```
+------------------+------------+------------+
| Agent / Resource | Resource_1 | Resource_2 |
+------------------+------------+------------+
| Agent_1          |          1 |          0 |
| Agent_2          |          1 |          1 |
| Agent_3          |          0 |          1 |
| Agent_4          |          1 |          1 |
+------------------+------------+------------+
```

I want to take this graph and do some relational algebra on this by doing something like this:

```
Suppose X = the above matrix

Y = X * X.transpose()

Y=
+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Agent / Agent | Agent_1 | Agent_2 | Agent_3 | Agent_4 |
+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Agent_1       | X       | 1       | 0       | 1       |
| Agent_2       | 1       | X       | 1       | 1       |
| Agent_3       | 0       | 1       | X       | 1       |
| Agent_4       | 1       | 1       | 1       | X       |
+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I would like to know if there's an easy way to do this with an already created NetworkX graph. The reason I was wondering if there was any way to do this with the methods available to me in NetworkX is that my Graph is a little more complex than just a name and a value so I would like to hopefully save myself from doing this via the brute-force method.

Comment: Please read [ask]. What have you learned about representing & querying trees/hierarchies relationally? Including CTEs in SQL. But also learn about relational design, because we transpose a well-designed relational table by *swapping column names*. Your 2nd table is for final output to humans, but is a poor representation for manipulation. So is your 1st table in a similar way. Also learn about pivoting--but if it isn't the last step for output then you're doing things wrong. PS You want code blocks not code snippets.

Comment: Are you basically just trying to create a graph of agents with two agents connected iff they connect to the same resource?  If so, read up on `nx.projected_graph`: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.projection.projected_graph.html#networkx.algorithms.bipartite.projection.projected_graph

Comment: @philipxy - it's not clear to me why OP would need to know anything about CTEs in SQL or relational design for this question about a networkx digraph.  I don't, but I'm fairly certain I can answer the question once I get a little clarification.

Comment: @Joel The title/tags refer to *relational algebra*. The asker doesn't *need* to know about CTEs, it's just helpful to understand how relations are manipulated by operators. Relational design is relevant because if you are going to solve a problem in terms of relations then it is helpful to know "good" ways to characterize it.

Comment: What does the 2nd table have to do with the 1st? You have not explained anything by saying "transpose" & what you mean is not obvious from your example. Do you mean what was guessed in another comment? You also don't explain "adjacency matrix based on the edges", which means nothing. You also don't clearly distinguish relations vs illustrations/matrices. Do you realize that both tables are poorly designed when modeling relationally? Compared to a table on (a,r) "a -> r" (whatever "->" means) & a table on (a, b) (guessing from your example, maybe something like "for some r [a -> r & b -> r]")?